# I cannot add user to Firebase Authetnication using Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've looked at some Youtube tutorials, read some threads here and tried to grasp the documentation on the Firebase page, but it just seems that it's completely not working for me. I am trying just to add manually written (in source code) user to test it out, but that does not work. Tried writing "toast" messages in both of the "if" conditions, but none of the toast seems to pop out. I can add user manually on to the firebase through their page and when I did it and tried to add the same user, I think I've got the "user created" toast for one time, but when I tried again I got nothing, so I don't even really know.

Edit: Sorry if I mispoke, but I am not trying to add to database, I want to add to the authentication, since I got the part with databases covered, but the authentication isn't working.

Edit2: Either it was something with cache/AVD's or I don't know, but after allowing internet (on manifest) it seems working. I don't know if that helped, but I marked the answer under which the comment to add that thing is as a solution.

My code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference myRef;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);;
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        Button buttonLogin;
        buttonLogin = findViewById(R.id.loginLoginButton);
        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword("example@example.com", "exempliore852").addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                    {
                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });
  }
```

I am constantly getting this error in logcat:

```
2020-05-08 19:13:41.036 1791-2322/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
```

Full logcat of errors (since Verbose logcat is too much of size for pastebin):
https://pastebin.com/2icthFwN

What am I doing it wrong?

Edit: Sorry if I mispoke, but I am not trying to add to database, I want to add to the authentication, since I got the part with databases covered, but the authentication isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to create a user with email and password and to get users stored in Firebase Database you have to write the method that will get users stored in a database. Have a look

```
 mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(edtEmail.getText().toString(), edtPassword.getText().toString())
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Signing up successful.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            // method to get username stored in database
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                                    .child("users").child(task.getResult().getUser().getUid())
                                    .child("username")
                                    .setValue(edtUsername.getText().toString());

                            UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                    .setDisplayName(edtUsername.getText().toString())
                                    .build();

                            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().updateProfile(profileUpdates)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "User " +
                                                        edtUsername.getText().toString() + " updated",
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                            transitionToMainActivity();
                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Signing up failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I will check it in a bit, but just to be clear: I want to add users to authentication page (so  you could log-in), but not to the real-time database. Sorry if I misspoke before. Problem is, it's not adding anything to Authentication and none of the "Toast" messages shows up.

Comment: Try this, I am pretty sure it will work... If you don't want to add users to a database then just remove the method to get username stored in the database. And also check in AndroidManifest.xml class if you have internet permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: That's really weird. I haven't tried your code, but started by adding internet permission to manifest, seemed like still not working, so just tried to comment out a block of the code just to leave the authentication part. Still seemed not working, but it took some time and users started getting created. Uncommented the other part of the code and it's all working as well, so... maybe the internet permission was actually the thing. It's weird that I haven't seen it mentioned in the tutorials or documentation; maybe I overlooked. Regardless, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't adding anything at all to Realtime Database.  It's just creating a user account with Firebase Authentication, which is a different product.  You can see user accounts in the Firebase console in the "Authentication" product area.

If you want to add user data to the database, you'll need to write that yourself.

Comment: No, that's the thing, it's not adding anything to authentication. And that's what I am trying to do, since I got the database thing completed and it's working fine, but the authentication part is not working. Or do I must have an user with "email" and "password" details in database first to add him to authentication?

Comment: No, createUserWithEmailAndPassword should add a new account if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: That's what I thought. I did add the dependencies to firebase authentication as well and if there would be some problem, at least the "not" if toast should show, right? I will maybe try create a new project just to test out this adding user thing, maybe something else is wrong.